# No callback on init with FB Connect Javascript API on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, facebook

I am using FB.init to connect using FB connect javascript APIs. I have tested the behavior on FF and IE and it works absolutely fine. I get the expected callbacks, but for Safari, the callbacks are not received. Can someone help me with this.

Following is the code I am using to connect:

```
FB.init("<?php echo $api_key;?>", "xd_receiver.htm",{"ifUserConnected":loadFriends, "ifUserNotConnected": fb_Notlogin});
```

None of these methods get called after this FB.init method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. My mistake, I added two init calls and in Safari the other one was getting called. Fixed and working.